# How can I access item.name, item.price,item.tag, item.incart using a variable

Tags: javascript, html

How can I access item.name, item.price,item.tag, item.incart inside the div using a variable.  I have tried all the ways using DOM.

```js
function summary() {

  myObj = `{"naturalstraight":{"name":"Natural Straight","tag":"naturalstraight","price":95,"incart":2}}` // localStorage.getItem("productsInCart");
  myObj = JSON.parse(myObj);
  console.log(myObj);

  if (myObj && summaryContainer) {
    summaryContainer.innerHTML = '';
    Object.values(myObj).map(item => {
      summaryContainer.innerHTML += `
      <div class="product">
        <ion-icon name="close-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
        <img src="./images/${item.tag}.jpg">
        <span>${item.name}</span> 
      </div> 
      <div class="price">$${item.price}</div> 
      <div class="quantity">
        <span>${item.incart}</span>
      </div> 
      <div class="total">$${item.incart * item.price},00 </div>`;
    });
  }
}

summary();
```

```html
<div class="col-50">
  <div id="orderSummary">
    <h2>Order summary</h2>

    <div class="summary-container" style="padding-bottom: 0px;">
      <div class="summary" style="width:800px">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` stack snippet editor and add relevant HTML AND an example of your object

Comment: @mplungjan  Added my HTML

Comment: And some JSON??? Please replace `localStorage.getItem("productsInCart");` with some valid JSON

Comment: localStorage.getItem("productsInCart");  is 
{"naturalstraight":{"name":"Natural Straight","tag":"naturalstraight","price":95,"incart":2}}

As the span text changes,I need to grab the text and set it.

Comment: As you can see you get a console error. Please fix. `const summaryContainer = document.getElementById("summary-container")` is missing somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I add the path to the div, the code works

```
const summaryContainer = document.querySelector("#orderSummary .summary-container > .summary");
```

```js
 
function summary() {
  const summaryContainer = document.querySelector("#orderSummary .summary-container > .summary");
  myObj = `{"naturalstraight":{"name":"Natural Straight","tag":"naturalstraight","price":95,"incart":2}}` // localStorage.getItem("productsInCart");
  myObj = JSON.parse(myObj);
  if (myObj && summaryContainer) {
    summaryContainer.innerHTML = '';
    Object.values(myObj).map(item => {
      summaryContainer.innerHTML += `
      <div class="product">
        <ion-icon name="close-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
        <img src="./images/${item.tag}.jpg">
        <span>${item.name}</span> 
      </div> 
      <div class="price">$${item.price}</div> 
      <div class="quantity">
        <span>${item.incart}</span>
      </div> 
      <div class="total">$${item.incart * item.price},00 </div>`;
    });
  }
}
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  summary();
})
```

```html
<script type="module" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/5.1.0-0/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule="" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/5.1.0-0/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
<div class="col-50">
  <div id="orderSummary">
    <h2>Order summary</h2>
    <div class="summary-container" style="padding-bottom: 0px;">
      <div class="summary" style="width:800px">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```